# Multiple interfaces contained in one List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, generic-list

Is there a way to define the type in a generic class like List to have contain objects which only implent **multiple** interfaces? Possibly class type **and** interfaces.

For example:

```
List<myObjectBase, IDisposable, IClonable> myList;
```

Comment: Are you saying your wanting the option of those three types to be able to be stored in your list? (so you could stuff a myObjectBase a class that implements IDisposable or a class that implements IClonable?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but how about this:

```
class MyList<T> : List<T>
  where T : myObjectBase, IDisposable, IClonable
{
}
```

This way you can only add objects to the list which derive from the base and implement those interfaces.

Comment: This is a great solution. For the record, what does class inheritance actually cost memory and cpu wise? How much more expensive would it be to say have a single non-inherited class compared to one that inherits 5 times? may not be as elegant if I had to make many like this. For my current case though, this is great.

Comment: @jsmars It's cheap enough that you don't need to care. The cost is fixed; it doesn't matter how long the chain of inheritance is. .NET implements this essentially the same way as C++, using a "vtable" - [Wikipedia's article on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) is not bad.

Comment: Don't like that solution. To introduce a derived List<T> type to express a commonality of the elements in the container "feels" wrong to me.

Comment: @Achim for what it's worth, I'm the one who gave your answer that upvote - I really thought _that_ was going to be the accepted answer :)

Comment: How would you use this? For example, assume `Foo` and `Bar` each inherit the base class and interfaces. `MyList<Foo>` can't hold `bar`, and `MyList<Bar>` can't hold `foo`. You still need a common ancestor to inherit/implement all constrained type parameters so that `foo` and `bar` can coexist in the single list. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @romkyns: I don't begrundge it to you! ;-) No problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

No. In that case you would have to express that in the following way:

```
public class CommonStuff : MyObjectBase, IDisposable, IClonable {}
```

Then you can write:

```
List<CommonStuff> myList;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, multiple generic parameters are not supported.

It wouldn't make much sense either. There would be no benefit of using the generic `List<T>` class over something like an `ArrayList`. You would lose all of the type safety benefits and you'd wind up still having to cast things all over the place.

The better option would be to create a composite class that handles all of the things you want to do...and then use that:

```
public class CommonBase : MyBaseClass, ICloneable, IDisposable
{
}
```

And then use that as your generic parameter:

```
var newList = new List<CommonBase>();
```

Comment: In .net is is possible to have a method accept parameters of generic types with multiple constraints.  If one could specify that a List&lt;T&gt; will only store objects which implement IFoo and IBar, then one could pass items from that list to a routine needing a type which implements IFoo and IBar.  Otherwise, if IFoo and IBar don't have a common ancestor, there's no nice way of casting an object of some unknown type which implements IFoo and IBar in such a fashion as to allow it to be passed to a routine that demands that its passed-in object implement IFoo and IBar.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the simplest solution for adding multiple interfaces that worked for me.

List<ICommonInterface> myList = new List<ICommonInterface>()

```
myFirstClass m1C = new myFirstClass();
mySecondClass m2C = new mySecondClass();

myList.Add(m1C);
myList.Add(m2C);

foreach (var item in myList)
{
    item.Clone();
    item.Dispose();
}

class myFirstClass : ICommonInterface  
{  
// implement interface methods  
}  

class mySecondClass : ICommonInterface  
{  
// implement interface methods  
}  


interface ICommonInterface : IDisposable, IClonable  
{  
}  


interface IDisposable  
{  
    void Dispose(){}  
}  

interface IClonable     
{  
    void Clone(){}  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach that may be helpful is to define an interface ISelf<out T> whose one member, Self, simply returns "this" as a T; then for any interface IWhatever that might be combined, define a generic version IWhatever<out T> which inherits both the IWhatever and ISelf<T>.  In that case, a class Whizbang which implements IFoo<Whizbang> and IBar<Whizbang> will implicitly implement ISelf<Whizbang>, IFoo<IBar<Whizbang>>, IBar<IFoo<Whizbang>>, etc.  A routine which needs something that implements both IFoo and IBar can accept a parameter of type IFoo<IBar>; that parameter will implement IFoo; its Self property will implement IBar.  Any object which implements multiple interfaces using this pattern may be cast to a nested interface type of the given form using some or all of the interfaces, listed in any order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) and can check the Type of an object in this list - maybe it is handier.

```
if(list[i] is Type)
```

Comment: The question is about how to *increase* static type safety checking and your suggestion is to *abandon* static type safety checking. This seems like a step in the opposite direction, rather than a solution to the problem posed. Also, use List<object>, not ArrayList, if you want a list of arbitrary objects.